# Understanding z-index stacking order

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I am a little confused about using `z-index` to decide stack order.

I do not quite understand how browsers treat elements with the `position` property in conjunction to those without it.

Is there a general rule to decide the stack order of elements whether it has explicitly positioned elements or not?

Examples of different situations are appreciated. Generally speaking:

1. mixed sibling `<div>`s with position set and without position set.
2. nested `<div>`s mixed with sibling `<div>`s with position set and without position set.

Comment: Don't you understand the concept of "z-index" or the concept of "position"?
You could try to explain your example with actual code.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Basics of the CSS `z-index` property

*A Simple Concept*

The `z-index` property is based on a simple concept: Elements with higher values will sit in front of elements with lower values along the z-axis. So if you apply `z-index: 1` to `div.box1`, and `div.box2` has a `z-index: 0`, then `div.box1` will overlay `div.box2`.

In terms of the z-axis, it refers to depth on a three-dimensional plane. On your computer it can be interpreted as the plane on which objects move closer and farther from you. (Learn more about the [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).)

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridimensional)</sup>

---

***`z-index` works on positioned elements***

Unless you're dealing with flex items or grid items, the `z-index` property works only on positioned elements. This means you can use `z-index` on elements with `position: absolute`, `position: relative`, `position: fixed` or `position: sticky`. If the element has `position: static` (the default value), or some other positioning scheme like a `float`, then `z-index` will have no effect.

As noted, although `z-index`, as defined in [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index), applies only to positioned elements, [**flex items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) and [**grid items**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) can create a stacking context even when `position` is `static`.

> [**4.3. Flex Item Z-Ordering**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting)
>
> Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks, except that order-modified document order is used in place of raw 
>   document order, and `z-index` values other than `auto` create a stacking context even if `position` is `static`.
>
> [**5.4. Z-axis Ordering: the `z-index` property**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order)
>
> The painting order of grid items is exactly the same as inline blocks, except that order-modified document order is 
>   used in place of raw document order, and `z-index` values other than `auto` create a stacking context even if 
>   `position` is `static`.

Here's a demonstration of `z-index` working on non-positioned flex items: https://jsfiddle.net/m0wddwxs/

---

***Stacking Contexts***

Once an element is positioned and a `z-index` is applied, a stacking context is created.

(Also see: [Full list of circumstances where a stacking context is created.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context))

The stacking context is a set of rules for managing the positioned element with `z-index`, and its descendants. These rules govern the placement of child elements in the *stacking order* and the scope of the property's influence.

Essentially, the stacking context limits the `z-index` scope to the element itself, and its child elements cannot affect the stacking order of elements in another stacking context.

If you've ever tried to apply increasingly higher `z-index` values only to find that the element never moves out in front, you could be trying to overlay an element in a different stacking context.

> Groups of elements with a common parent that move forward or backward
>   together in the stacking order make up what is known as a stacking
>   context. A full understanding of stacking contexts is key to really
>   grasping how z-index and the stacking order work.
>
> Every stacking context has a single HTML element as its root element.
>   When a new stacking context is formed on an element, that stacking
>   context confines all of its child elements to a particular place in
>   the stacking order. That means that if an element is contained in a
>   stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order, there is no way
>   to get it to appear in front of another element in a different
>   stacking context that is higher in the stacking order, even with a
>   z-index of a billion!
>
> *~ [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)*

---

***Stacking Order***

CSS adheres to a stacking order when laying out elements on a page. These are the stacking rules when there is no `z-index` specified, from farthest to closest:

1. Backgrounds and borders of the root element
2. Non-positioned, non-floating block elements, in the order they appear in the source code
3. Non-positioned floating elements, in the order they appear in the source code
4. Inline elements
5. Positioned elements, in the order they appear in the source code

If a `z-index` property is applied, the stacking order is modified:

1. Backgrounds and borders of the root element
2. Positioned elements with a `z-index` of less than 0
3. Non-positioned, non-floating block elements, in the order they appear in the source code
4. Non-positioned floating elements, in the order they appear in the source code
5. Inline elements
6. Positioned elements, in the order they appear in the source code
7. Positioned elements with `z-index` of greater than 0

*Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)*

---

Bottom line: ***Once you understand stacking contexts, `z-index` is easy.***

---

For examples of `z-index` in action see: [How z-index works!](http://www.cssmojo.com/extras/everything_you_always_wanted_to_know_about_z-index_but_were_afraid_to_ask/)

For a brief but highly informative article explaining `z-index` (including how `opacity` affects the stacking order) see: [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

For a complete rundown on `z-index`, with many examples and illustrations, see: [MDN Understanding CSS `z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)

And for a deep dive into stacking contexts read: [W3C Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/zindex.html)