# How to expand textarea without moving adjacent elements

Tags: html, css

I need to display three sets of information in an `aside` tag, and I have a `textarea` that I want to expand if information is too long. Every time I expand the first `textarea` though the text and `textarea` underneath it follow it as well. I am trying to get the `textarea` to go over the text and `textarea` underneath it. I tried its position as `relative` but that didn't work. Here is the example of the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/07em8L7s/

```
    <aside id="info">
        <div class="font">
        <div class="header">Aside</u></div>
        <b>Header 1:</b><br> 
        <textarea disabled style="background-color: white; max-height:160px; max-width:295px; position: relative;" cols="35" rows="3">info</textarea><br>   
        <b>Header 2:</b><br> 
        info<br>
        <b>Header 3:</b><br>
        <textarea disabled style="background-color: white; max-height:160px; max-width:295px;" cols="35" rows="3">info</textarea><br>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning) doesn't remove an element from the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) of the document. In other words, the relatively positioned element still impacts other elements in the layout.

You need to use [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). This removes the element from the normal flow and other elements won't even recognize its existence.

You may notice that adjacent elements suddenly disappear when you absolutely position the `textarea`. That's because other elements take up the space an absolutely positioned element was occupying before it was removed from the flow. The adjacent elements are behind the `textarea`.

You need to use the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties to move positioned elements.

But bottom line, when you absolutely position your `textarea` it won't affect the surrounding elements when you expand the box.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/07em8L7s/3/

Two more notes:

- You may need to use the [`z-index` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276) to determine the stacking order of positioned elements.
- Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. If there is no positioned ancestor then the `body` element is used.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for another answer, please do check my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/07em8L7s/4/

My solution is to wrap the textarea in a div with relative position and assigned the textarea inside with absolute position.

```
.textarea-wrapper { position: relative; max-height: 72px; }
.textarea-wrapper textarea {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

You will see the wrapper will have a max height value so the wrapper won't overflow when you resize the textarea's height. Hope it helps!