# How z-index works in CSS?

Tags: css, gwt, z-index

If I set the z-index of a popup panel to some value in GWT, say x, will it change the z-index of its parent panel (the default home page panel) as well?

In my GWT application, the z-index in css for a popup panel is 100. And then I manually change the z-index of the popup panel to some other value less than 100 using the `getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(99);` . After that, the popup panel is invisible.

Is it true that the background panel inherits the zIndex from the css file of its child popup panel which it didn't change accordingly when the popup panel uses the `getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(99);` ?

Comment: I would expect it to be a positioning proplem. Did you set any value for it ?

Comment: Addressing the title of your question specifically, and the body of your question possibly: [**Basics of the CSS `z-index` property**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```