# CSS transition and z-index

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a fixed top navbar with dropdowns. I want to slide the dropdown menus in on hover. I want that the menu is behind the navbar while sliding in. So I've simply tried to set the `z-index` of both elements which unfortunately did not work for me.

Here a simplified example ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpazWw?editors=110))

html

```
<div class="fixed-top">
  <span class="trigger">hover me</span>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.fixed-top {
  background: #3b5999;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.trigger {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.trigger:hover + .menu {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #1c7754;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -400px;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}
```

In case it's not clear what I want to do here a simple mspaint sketch ;)

[image: mspaint skills confirmed]

Comment: @Justcode my selector is actually working fine :D, your code results in the same as mine

Comment: Yes, but when I clicked it wasn't working as working now :P

Comment: This may help you better understand stacking contexts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276

Answer (score 11):

This is an extremely common error when beginning to work with stacking contexts in CSS.  Basically, you just have to remember that a child cannot exist in a different stacking context from a parent.

So if I have a non-static element (meaning an element with `position: anything-but-static [fixed, relative, absolute]`), and if that element has no non-static parent element, then it will be at stacking context level 1, no matter where it is in the DOM.  Now if that element has a non-static child element, that child will be at stacking context level 2.  **It cannot be on the same level (level 1) as its parent element**.  `z-index` can only affect elements on the same stacking context level, **it has nothing to do with elements on different stacking context levels.**

The solution is to restructure your HTML, or just use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element, thus:

```
.fixed-top {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed; /* The parent: stacking context level 1 */
}
.fixed-top:before {
    background: #3b5999;
    content:'';
    position: absolute; /* stacking context level 2 */
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.trigger {
    color: white;
    font-size: 33px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    position: relative; /* also stacking context level 2 */
    z-index: 2;
}
.trigger:hover + .menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.menu { /* bottom layer -- no stacking context necessary */
    z-index: 0;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #1c7754;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -400px;
    transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}
```

Note the comments denoting the stacking context levels.

And here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c5jt6bkk/) for an example.

Comment: Nice, still need to change it into this: `.trigger:hover + .menu, .menu:hover` so that the menu won't slide back up when the mouse leaves the `span`, +1

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I cannot tell that that is part of the spec, but I'll give you kudos for the suggestion.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I am seeing these symptoms now and after some messing with z-index, I started to feel strongly that children could never go under the parent.

I haven't solved it yet, but between your post and your examples, I should be able to.

Answer (score 4):

Try running the Code Snippet.

```css
.fixed-top {
  background: #3b5999;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.trigger {
  font-size: 33px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;  
  z-index: 3;  
}

.trigger:hover + .menu,
.menu:hover{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #1c7754;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -400px;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-top"></div>
<span class="trigger">hover me</span>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: This is working, thank you. But tbh I'm not very happy with it.. :D [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908787/is-there-a-css-selector-which-selects-an-element-outside-the-current-element)

Comment: Well, would be surprised if someone could achieve it without compromising your html's skeleton :)

Comment: @kolunar Umm, you mean like how I did in my answer?

Comment: @bowheart Ah! you nailed it, the pseudo :before masking does the trick :D

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want.

css code

```
    .fixed-top {
  background: #3b5999;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  position : fixed;
}

.trigger {
  z-index: 500;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position : absolute;
}

.trigger:hover + .menu {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu {
  z-index: -9999;
  position : relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #1c7754;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -400px;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

    <div class="fixed-top">
  <span class="trigger">hover me</span>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

here is the reference that you can check

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/