# Is there a css selector which selects an element outside the current element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Code explains better than words

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
</div>
<div class="outside"></div>
```

What I want to do

```
.child:hover ? .outside { }
```

where `?` is the selector I'm looking for

Comment: No, not when `.child:hover`. You can select `.outside` on `.parent:hover` though. And if your `.child` covers the entire space of the parent (which I doubt because it is a `span`) then `.child:hover` will effectively be equivalent to `.parent:hover`.

Comment: I doubt it. CSS selectors don't usually work in a way that would require traversing the DOM outwards (hence the previous sibling selector having bad support).

Comment: Selectors express structural relationships between elements. There is no conceivable relationship that can be expressed here using a single combinator (besides, perhaps, `.child:hover` *existing* somewhere in the document tree).

Comment: lets have a look to this http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: @BoltClock that sounds more like an answer than a comment ;)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483323/use-hover-to-modify-the-css-of-another-class

Comment: This looks like it can be *kind-a* done via `:target` pseudo-class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors/Using_the_%3Atarget_pseudo-class_in_selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selectors express structural relationships between elements. When you ask for a selector for an element that is "outside" another element, you're looking for a combinator that says "this element appears outside the containing scope of this other element".

There is no such combinator.

You could conceivably select specifically the `.outside` sibling of `.parent`, but then you run into another problem that [there is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) for matching `.parent` relative to `.child:hover` like there is for matching `.child:hover` relative to `.parent` (that is, `.parent > .child:hover`).

See also: [How do I select an element based on the state of another element in the page with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would to be to make the .parent class the element needed to hover over.

Then you could do

```
.parent:hover ~ .outside {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the following `html` structure:

```
<div class="parent">
<span class="child"></span>
</div>

<div class="outside"></div>
```

since there is no reliable parent selector in CSS, you can select `.outside` *only* in **5 ways**:

1. Directly.
2. *If* it is a sibling of `.parent`.
3. *If* it is a child of `.parent`.
4. *If* it is a sibling of `.child`.
5. *If* it is a child of `.child`.

Since `.outside` is neither a sibling nor a child of `.child`, nor is it a child of `.parent`, your only remaining relationship via which to select `.outside` is as a sibling of `.parent`.

This isn't really what you want, if you only want the presentation of `.outside` to change *only* when you hover over `.child`.

I'm no fan of using javascript to influence presentation when CSS can already handle the task, but in this case, CSS cannot handle the task and the javascript is elementary:

```js
var child = document.getElementsByClassName('child')[0];
var outside = document.getElementsByClassName('outside')[0];

function childHover() {
outside.classList.toggle('childhover');
}

function initialiseChildHover() {
child.addEventListener('mouseover',childHover,false);
child.addEventListener('mouseout',childHover,false);
}

window.addEventListener('load',initialiseChildHover,false);
```

```css
.parent {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.child {
display: inline-block; 
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 50px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}

.outside {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}

.outside.childhover {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span class="child"></span>
</div>
    
<div class="outside"></div>
```