# How do I select an element when one is nested and the other isnt?

Tags: html, css

Example:

```
 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="ruin">
        <span class="nest">hello</span>
        <span class="nest">bye</span>
    </div>

    <div class="select">select from nest span</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.nest ~ .select {
  color: red;
}

.wall .nest ~ .select {
  color: green;
}
```

I dont know how to select .select from .nest. Its not a sibling of it, or a child, or a parent.

Heres a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/cugok7v0/

**EDIT:**
Ok it is not possible with just css to select elements without a logical relationship between them. [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908787/is-there-a-css-selector-which-selects-an-element-outside-the-current-element) which I didnt find myself says it all.

Thankfully I found a good way to not need to nest the element and so I can use adjacent sibling selector.

Comment: You can try jQuery $('.nest').parent().next();

Comment: Are you expecting the `.select` text to be green? It is not clear what you are expecting to happen. If so, it is not possible.

Comment: No its impossible to do that with CSS selectors. Use jQuery [This will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908787/is-there-a-css-selector-which-selects-an-element-outside-the-current-element)

Comment: It's not possible with css.

Comment: Ok I see. I got around the problem anyway.