# Z-index does not work

Tags: css, z-index

I've been having some issues with the `z-index` property. Below you can see a example:

```
<div id="popup">
  <div id="button">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="trip">
</div>

<div id="gray">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cf5dhv39/1/

As you can see, I want that the div `#button` overlay the div `#gray` (like the div `#trip` does), but, no matter how much I increase the `z-index` in `#button`, the button doesn't overlay the `#gray`.

Comment: This is an issue of *stacking contexts*. This may be helpful: [Basics of the `z-index` property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276).

Comment: Please post relevant CSS code *directly in the question*, not only on JSFiddle.

Comment: Very useful Michael, thanks.
Sorry Gothdo, next time i'll do that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `#popup` has smaller **z-index** than `#gray` and `#button` is child of `#popup` so it will always be behind `#gray`, but you can place `#gray` inside `#popup`

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

#popup{
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#button{  
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: green;
}

#trip{
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#gray{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: gray;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div id="button"></div>
  <div id="gray"></div>
</div>

<div id="trip"></div>
```

Comment: i put gray inside popup and works fine here, thanks !