# z-index on sibling absolute elements

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I'm trying to grasp why the blue divs in this example are not always on top? i.e. how come red div #2 is on top of blue child 1.

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
.red1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.red2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 250px;
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 130px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red1">
  <div class="blue">
    blue child 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="red2">
  <div class="blue">
    blue child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/h0s2t6nm/10/)

Comment: I am expecting the blue child in the first red div to be on top of red div 2. Both blue divs have a z-index of 9 and both reds have z-index of 1 so how can a red ever be on top of a blue?

Answer (score 6):

Because `.red1` and `.red2` form different stacking contexts.

The elements within one stacking context do not participate along with the elements within another stacking context.

If you give `.red2` a `z-index: -1`, you will get the behavior you expect ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h0s2t6nm/11/)).

That's because `.red1` and `.red2` are both absolutely positioned with no positioned ancestor. This means the root element is their immediate ancestor, and [the root element forms a stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

More details here:

- [Basics of the CSS `z-index` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276)
- [Understanding z-index: How does this element appear in front of its parent's sibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38310538/3597276)

Comment: I would add that if you remove z-index from both red divs you will also get the needed result (the answer of the OP was removed so may we can add it here)

Answer (score 1):

Stacking contexts — whether local or root — follow a set of rules that determine the stacking and painting order of elements. Children of a stacking context are painted from bottom to top in the following order. if you flip the order you will see the change. meaning div.red2 then div.red1

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
.red1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.red2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 250px;
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 130px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red2">
  <div class="blue">
    blue child 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="red1">
  <div class="blue">
    blue child 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add more details to your answer? It will make easier for people to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution, if I understood the stacking order correctly

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
.red1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.red2 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 250px;
  background: red;
}
.blue {
/*
regardless of z-index values
*/
  z-index: auto;
  z-index: -5;
  z-index: 56654;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 130px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red1">RED1 <!-- stacking order = B -->
  <div class="blue"> <!-- stacking order = B.b -->
    blue child 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="red2">RED2 <!-- stacking order = A -->
  <div class="blue"> <!-- stacking order = A.a  -->
    blue child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

The display will be in the following order (stacking order):
A  (RED2)
A.a  (BLUE CHILD 2)
B  (RED1)
B.b  (BLUE CHILD 1)