# Images overlap collapsed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I couldn't find anything like this on internet so I'm asking you guys! The problem is that my icons overlap my collapsed navbar.

[image: Image here]

**My code:**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="">
                                            <div id="black">
                                            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                                              <div class="container-fluid">
                                                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                      </button>

                                                      <a class="img-responsive col-xs-4 col-sm-8 col-md-10 col-lg-12" href="#"> 
                                                        <img id="logo2" alt="Logo" class="" height="80%" width="73%" src="images/logo1.png"> 
                                                      </a>
                                                </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="">
                        <div id="black">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse"                             role="navigation">
                          <div class="container-fluid">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  </button>
                                  <a class="img-responsive col-xs-4 col-sm-8 col-md-10 col-lg-12" href="#"> 
                                    <img id="logo2" alt="Logo" class="" height="80%" width="73%" src="images/logo1.png"> 
                                  </a>
                            </div>

<!-- Navbar contentas -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="visible-lg" href="#">Pagrindinis</a></li>
        <li><a class="visible-lg" href="#">Kontaktai</a></li>
        <li><a class="visible-lg" href="#">Apie mus</a></li>
        <li><a class="visible-lg" href="#">Paslaugos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pagrindinis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apie mus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontaktai</a></li>
            <li><a href="tel:+" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Mygtukas', eventAction: 'Telefonas'});">+370 67651008</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><p class="navbar-text" style="margin-left: 15px;" >Already have an account?</p></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                     <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Login via
                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                                </div>
                                or
                                 <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                             <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                                             </label>
                                        </div>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom text-center">
                                New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>          
    </div>
        <div id="mint"></div>
            <div class="" id="background1">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="logo1" src="images/logo1.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p id="p1" class="" >A great new free psd theme to showcase your<br>new application.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="sicons">
                    <img class="img-responsive col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4" src="images/icon1.png"/>
                    <img class="img-responsive col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;" src="images/icon2.png"/>
                    <img class="img-responsive col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4" src="images/icon3.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
        body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    #black {
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #282828;
    }
    /*------------NAVBAR DALYKAI-------------------------*/

    #login-dp{
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 14px 14px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    }
    #login-dp .help-block{
    font-size:12px    
    }
    #login-dp .bottom{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    clear:both;
    padding:14px;
    }
    #login-dp .social-buttons{
    margin:12px 0    
    }
    #login-dp .social-buttons a{
    width: 49%;
    }
    #login-dp .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .btn-fb{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#3b5998;
    }
    .btn-fb:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#496ebc 
    }
    .btn-tw{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#55acee;
    }
    .btn-tw:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#59b5fa;
    }
    @media(max-width:768px){
    #login-dp{
        background-color: inherit;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #login-dp .bottom{
        background-color: inherit;
        border-top:0 none;
    }
    }
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



    #mint {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    }

    #background1
    {
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url("images/background1.jpg"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    }


    .p {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    }

    #logo1 {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 11%;
    }

    #logo2 {
    margin-top: 5%;
    }

    #p1 {
    font-family: helvica-thin;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    }

    #sicons {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20%;
    background-color: grey;
    }

    #sicons a:hover {
    color: green;
    }

    #white {
    height: 245px;
    }

    #icons {
    position: absolute;
    }

    #iframe {
    /*margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 350px;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 560px; 
    max-height: 315px;
    }

    #button {
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 141px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow:none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    }

    #p2 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #grey {
    height: 427px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    }

    #white1 {
    height: 468px;
    }

    #grey1 {
    min-height: 130px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    }
```

Comment: Banzay omg thanks a lot  how do did that? Super thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code sample, it appears the culprit is `#sicons` having a value of `position: absolute;`. Items positioned absolutely will always sit on top of relatively position items. Try assigning your navbar and `#sicons` containers with `z-index` values, making `#sicons`'s value lower than your navbar.

For more information about how `z-index` works, how it interacts with positioned elements, and the stacking order, check out the answer on this Stack Overflow question: ["Understanding z-index stacking order"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513540/understanding-z-index-stacking-order/32515284)

Comment: mm I made it relative and it still overlaps

Comment: And 1 more question should I ever use position: absolute? Because some times it doesnt work well with bootstrap.

Comment: @reimiux Does your navbar have a `z-index` value though? There's nothing wrong with using absolute positioning. It's easier to work with though if you understand how z-index works. I've updated my answer with an article for reference.

Comment: Yes they both have my #sicons have z-index: 1 and my navbar has z-index: 999. And icons still overlap them. And i learned how to use relative position for xs and s thanks to you! I was searching for that and I even though of writing a post here at stackoverflow. But i found out how by myself :) thanks a lot