# Sub-menu links still clickable when main menu drop-downs are closed

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to create a setup where I have a navbar, a collapsible menu within the navbar, and website content.

Sorry for the bad example but kind of like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2nqchLpf/

As you can see if you hover over the sub-menu links when the dropdown is not expanded, you can still click on them.

How can I get the links to display behind the content while having the navbar display over everything?

I have applied `z-index` like this:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.big-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky with `z-index`, considering stacking order and other `z-index` characteristics. Here's a complete run-down: [Basics of the CSS `z-index` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276)

But for a simple and easy solution, since you're already using `position: absolute`, just move the sub-links off the screen.

So instead of this:

```
.big-dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 4em;
  width: 100%;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

Try something like this:

```
.big-dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px; /* adjustment */
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 4em;
  width: 100%;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1!important;
  left: 0; /* new */
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2nqchLpf/1/)

Comment: bleh thanks for the question edits. That was easy to apply without having to change anything else. Works like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but if you replace

```
.show {
opacity: 1!important;
}
```

with

```
.show {
display: block;
}
```

and used

```
display: none;
```

instead of

```
opacity: 0;
```

it would work

Comment: I did think about doing this and it does work but the way the site is already setup I preferred to use opacity for the animations. Michael_B's answer is what I was looking for thanks.