# CSS Absolute Positioning & Z-Index

Tags: html, css, css-position

Say I have the following HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.red, .green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  z-index: 400;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the red box to appear on top of the green box. But it doesn't. The `.wrapper` has `z-index` of only `99` whereas `.red` has `z-index: 100`. Are there any hacks top produce `.red` on top?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to give the wrapper thats containing both of those `div`s a `z-index` because it's containing both of those `div`s. Get rid of the `z-index` on the `.wrapper`. and leave the `.red` class a `z-index` of 400 and the red box will appear on top of the green one:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.red, .green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  z-index: 400;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting both containers to `z-index: 99`. Therefore, since the `z-index` is the same for both, source order decides placement on the z-axis.

The `.wrapper` element with the green div comes last in your code, so it prevails. (Switch the order of the `.wrapper` elements, and the red wins out.)

The `z-index: 400` on the red child is having no effect since the [stacking order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276) that matters is that of the containers.

Try this:

```css
.wrapper:first-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper:last-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.red, .green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if those `.wrapper` divs were auto-generated and I did not have the count or the order beforehand?

Comment: Can you post a more detailed example? Also, read the post linked to in my answer. It may answer your question.

Comment: I was trying to make a custom Select2 component, and the dropdown z-index was messed up. Anyway, thanks for the answers, I'm reverting back to other libraries.