# z-index not working in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a flex container with 3 flex items.

First flex item contains 2 classes (`.flex-item` and `.overlay`).

I want to overlay image over the flex item. I tried it by adding `z-index` and position but it's not working.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 15em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}

.overlay {
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/check-circle_318-31777.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100px 80px;
  z-index: 110;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;    /* Real browsers */
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);   /* MSIE */
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item overlay">
    Image
    <img src="http://7bna.net/images/home-images/home-images-0.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  </div>

</div>
```

[Please see the code in codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEmgGb)

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwPJxK)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, the `.overlay` class establishes a background image on the *parent element*.

In your HTML, the `img` element places an image *as a child of the `.overlay` parent*.

Per the rules of [***`z-index`*** *stacking contexts*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276), a child cannot appear behind the parent. Therefore, the background image (parent) cannot appear in front of the `img` (child).

That's why your `img` is always out front, irrespective of `z-index`.

But there is an easy solution to this problem. Use an absolutely-positioned pseudo-element:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 15em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0; /* https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276 */
}

.overlay::after {
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/check-circle_318-31777.jpg) no-repeat center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0.6;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item overlay">
    <img src="http://7bna.net/images/home-images/home-images-0.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWbawO?editors=1100)

Answer (score 3):

Your *check* is background and *house* is content so background can't be above content. Move *check* to another element.

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

.flex-item{
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 15em;
  border:2px solid red;
  height:100px;
}

.overlay:before {
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/check-circle_318-31777.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100px 80px;
  z-index: 110;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6; /* Real browsers */
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* MSIE */
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item overlay">
    Image
    <img src="http://7bna.net/images/home-images/home-images-0.jpg" />
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
  </div>  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%; 
} 
.image { 
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
} 
.overlay { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}
.container:hover .overlay { 
  opacity: 1;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://7bna.net/images/home-images/home-images-0.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/check-circle_318-31777.jpg" width="50%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `position: absolute` not `relative` in `.overlay`