# CSS z-index and stacking contexts

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to better understand the CSS `z-index` property and stacking contexts.

As practice, I've built a little HTML demo containing some elements, and I am trying to order them in all kinds of different orders using `z-index` positioning only.

The basic demo is available below, or in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2773hggL/1/).

```css
#d1 { /*z-index: ;*/ position: relative; }
#d2 { /*z-index: ;*/ position: relative; }
#d3 { /*z-index: ;*/ position: relative; }
#d4 { /*z-index: ;*/ position: relative; }

#d1, #d2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

#d3, #d4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#d1 {
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.6);
}

#d2 {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.6);
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#d3 {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.6);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#d4 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.6);
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="d1">#d1
    <div id="d3">#d3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="d2">#d2
    <div id="d4">#d4</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now, is it possible to stack the elements in the above demo in the following order (farthest to closest): `#d1, #d4, #d2, #d3` ?

(To clarify, the order in the initial demo is: `#d1, #d3, #d2, #d4`)

---

### Disclaimer:

Prior to asking this question, I have actually searched and read about `z-index` and stacking contexts. I am familiar with the general rules and specification of how `z-index` works, and when stacking contexts are created.

Hence, this is not a general "I do not understand how z-index works" question, and therefore it is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513540/understanding-z-index-stacking-order).

This question refers to the specific case that I have presented above in as much detail as I could. What I ask for is a very specific answer to that specific question - either "Yes, this can be done like so...", or "No, this can't be achieved, because..."

Comment: This order > #d1, #d4, #d2, #d3 means that d1 is under d4 is under d2 is under d3 ?

Comment: If you give a parent div a z-index value, the z-index values of its child elements will be relevant to it.

Comment: @Tomislav Svecak: Yes, that's what "farthest to closest" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, is it possible to stack the elements in the above demo in the following order (farthest to closest): `#d1, #d4, #d2, #d3` ?

No, it is not possible. The farthest you can go is `#d1`, `#d4`, `#d2` with the following:

```css
#d1 { z-index: -1; position: relative; }
#d2 {  }
#d3 {  }
#d4 { z-index: -1; position: relative; }
```

... but this results in `#d1` creating a stacking context for `#d3`, which prevents `#d3` from ever being painted above `#d2` or `#d4` because the negative z-index of `#d1` causes `#d1` itself to be painted below `#d4` (as two boxes with the same stack level will be painted in source order, and `#d4` comes after `#d1`) and `#d2`.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. not without changing your HTML - but I assume from your question that it's the CSS you're trying to understand.

z-index of a child is tied to the z-index of the parent. You can change the layers of D1 and D2 and switch them front and back. But the child of D2 will share that layer. Like this:

```
D1 {z-index:1} // bottom layer
  child1{z-index:100}
  child2{z-index:2000}
D2 {z-index: 2}
  child1{z-index:3}
  child2{z-index:50} // top layer
```

Note that D1:child2 has an index of 2000 but will appear behind D2:child1 even though that has an index of 3.

Answer (score 0):

You must set height z-index for element you want to be above, if I understand correctly your question. 
For example:

```
#d4 {
    z-index: 10;
}
#d3 {
    z-index: 9;
}
```

id d4 will be about d3.

Z-index also support negative values. Other important note is the DOM element will be in directly report with parent. So if a child has z-index: 999 his parent z-index: 10, and sibling of his parent 15, child will not be over parent sibling.