# Is globally defined position:relative to page container a good practice?

Tags: css

My application has multiple pages and each page has a top class `.page-container`. There is dispute on setting relative positioning for page container. My understanding is all the content is relative to the page container. Any thoughts?

The example is as below:

```css
.page-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.page-content {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main class='page-container'>
    <div class='page-content'>content for each page </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Have it or not, it is okay since a container that has a position:relative is needed when you have an element that is in absolute position and that you want that element to be on top of that container only. Other than that, forming a layout is easy with just some clearfix, display, float, and some other attributes you can use in making a layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Short:*** Use `relative` when you need to position inner `absolute` child elements respective to that `relative` element.

---

Setting `position:relative;` [(instead of the default `static`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) has specific uses, but yes, basically there's nothing wrong in doing so.
But after setting the position to `relative` you should know that i.e: `absolute` positioned **child** elements will be relative to that parent, instead to the first outer positioned grandparent.

Setting `position` (in general) is also wise when doing `overflow`.

In this [jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/hebanu/edit?html,css,output) remove the CSS `position: relative;` comments and see the difference.

In your specific case where your `position:relative;` `<main>` is an immediate child of `body`, acting as a container, `position:relative;` could be a smart choice, although not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well default `position` of div is `static` (i.e.`position:static`), so by assigning a position value to it as relative (i.e.`position:relative`) thus you are assigning new position to it, which is bit similar but only differs when your child element is positioned as absolute (i.e.`position:absolute`). So it's okay to assign `position:relative` multiple times and not too. But surely assign when your child element is positioned as `absolute`.

You can visit this which explain more about the difference between `poistion:static` and `poistion:relative`, [Here....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011211/difference-between-static-and-relative-positioning)

**1st example** by assigning `position:static` to parent and `absolute` to `child` and `top:0`, you can see that **child element goes outside of parent div**.

```css
.page-container {
  position:static;
  background-color:#111;
  padding: 10px;
}

.page-content {
  background-color: pink;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
 <main class='page-container'>
    <div class='page-content'>content for each page </div>
  </main>
```

**2nd example** by assigning `position:relative` to parent and `absolute` to `child` and same `top:0`, you can see that **child element remains inside of parent div takes child to top position at zero**.

```css
.page-container {
  position:relative;
  background-color:#111;
  padding: 10px;
}

.page-content {
  background-color: pink;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
 <main class='page-container'>
    <div class='page-content'>content for each page </div>
  </main>
```