# CSS: universally apply postion: relative

Tags: css, css-position

It can be inconvenient to deal with elements which resolve to `position: static`. A potentially easy way to avoid this entirely is:

```
* { position: relative; }
```

Imagine a large, complex webapp which functions perfectly. What unexpected ramifications could result from introducing this rule to every page in such a webapp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is globally defined position:relative to page container a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863750/is-globally-defined-positionrelative-to-page-container-a-good-practice)

Comment: Good catch @Simplicius! This is a duplicate.

Comment: Nothing really. By [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), they kind of imply that relative is the same as static but it allows movement around the screen